# Is there a way to disable certain cipher and protocols at openssl level?

Tags: ssl, openssl, security

At application level there is sometimes no (easy) way to, say, disable SSLv2 etc.
What about at openssl level (of course for applications that use the openssl shared libs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is possible to compile **OpenSSL** without *SSLv2* support, but then you may have to re-compile most (if not all) of the application relying on it. I believe the Ubuntu guys [do something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206546/undefined-symbol-sslv2-method). If you think going this way, it may be simpler to just patch your application to use *SSLv3* or *TLSv1*.

According to [this blog post](http://adamyoung.net/Disable-SSLv2-System-Wide) your other options are application-specific configuration (if your application supports it), or the use of **stunnel**.

Other than that, I'm not aware of any other option to disable specific SSL versions or algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

I do it with apache config:
In my VirtualHost  thise code enables only SSL3 but disable everything else f.e. TLS and SSL2.

```
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3
   SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP
   SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/my.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/ssl/my.key
```